# PHP email form with attachments not working

Tags: php, file

I'm trying to use a PHP email form I found online that supports attachments, with a bit of extra code, but it's not working, I get a message saying "Sent", but no emails (I checked spam already).

Here is the php file:

```
function multi_attach_mail($to, $subject, $message, $senderMail, $senderName, $files){

    $from = $senderName." <".$senderMail.">";
    $headers = "From: $from";

    // boundary
    $semi_rand = md5(time());
    $mime_boundary = "==Multipart_Boundary_x{$semi_rand}x";

    // headers for attachment
    $headers .= "\nMIME-Version: 1.0\n" . "Content-Type: multipart/mixed;\n" . " boundary=\"{$mime_boundary}\"";

    // multipart boundary
    $message = "--{$mime_boundary}\n" . "Content-Type: text/html; charset=\"UTF-8\"\n" .
    "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\n\n" . $message . "\n\n";

    // preparing attachments
    if(count($files) > 0){
        for($i=0;$i<count($files);$i++){
            if(is_file($files[$i])){
                $message .= "--{$mime_boundary}\n";
                $fp =    @fopen($files[$i],"rb");
                $data =  @fread($fp,filesize($files[$i]));
                @fclose($fp);
                $data = chunk_split(base64_encode($data));
                $message .= "Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name=\"".basename($files[$i])."\"\n" .
                "Content-Description: ".basename($files[$i])."\n" .
                "Content-Disposition: attachment;\n" . " filename=\"".basename($files[$i])."\"; size=".filesize($files[$i]).";\n" .
                "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\n\n" . $data . "\n\n";
            }
        }
    }

    $message .= "--{$mime_boundary}--";
    $returnpath = "-f" . $senderMail;

    //send email
    $mail = @mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers, $returnpath);

    //function return true, if email sent, otherwise return fasle
    if($mail){ return TRUE; } else { return FALSE; }

}

$message = "Customer Contact"
. "\n" . "Name: " . $_POST['fullName']
. "\n" . "Email: " . $_POST['email']
. "\n" . "Phone: " . $_POST['phone']
. "\n" . "Current Phone: " . $_POST['currentPhone']
. "\n" . "Address: " . $_POST['address']
. "\n" . "Retailer: " . $_POST['retailer']
. "\n" . "Product Type: " . $_POST['productType']
. "\n" . "Specific Item: " . $_POST['item']
. "\n" . "Purchase Date: " . $_POST['purchaseDate']
. "\n" . "Invoice Number: " . $_POST['invoiceNumber']
. "\n" . "Issue: " . $_POST['issue']
. "\n" . "How did the issue happen?: " . $_POST['how']
. "\n" . "When did the issue occur?: " . $_POST['when']
. "\n" . "Have you done anything to try correcting the issue?: " . $_POST['customerTry'];

$to = 'someEmail@gmail.com';
$from = $_POST['email'];
$from_name = $_POST['fullName'];

//attachment files path array
$files = $_FILES['files'];
$subject = 'Customer Contact From Service Form';
$html_content = $message;

//call multi_attach_mail() function and pass the required arguments
$send_email = multi_attach_mail($to,$subject,$html_content,$from,$from_name,$files);

//print message after email sent
echo $send_email?"<h1> Mail Sent</h1><br>".$message:"<h1> Mail not SEND</h1>";
```

My form looks like this:

```
<form NOVALIDATE action="processContact.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="claimsForm" method="post" name="claimsForm">
  ..lots of fields...
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label claimsForm-field-header" for="customerTry">Photos:</label>
    <input type="file" id="files[]" name="files[]" multiple="multiple" />
    </div>

    <input class="green-btn" id="ss-submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

The function came with the form I downloaded, so I don't think there is a problem with it. I've been playing around with the code and trying different things, but no luck (I'm not a PHP guy).

**EDIT:**
Based on the suggestion below, I tried using phpMailer, following the example they have, here is my php file now:

```
/**
 * PHPMailer simple file upload and send example
 */
$msg = '';

$message = "Customer Contact"
. "\n" . "Name: " . $_POST['fullName']
. "\n" . "Email: " . $_POST['email']
. "\n" . "Phone: " . $_POST['phone']
. "\n" . "Current Phone: " . $_POST['currentPhone']
. "\n" . "Address: " . $_POST['address']
. "\n" . "Retailer: " . $_POST['retailer']
. "\n" . "Product Type: " . $_POST['productType']
. "\n" . "Specific Item: " . $_POST['item']
. "\n" . "Purchase Date: " . $_POST['purchaseDate']
. "\n" . "Invoice Number: " . $_POST['invoiceNumber']
. "\n" . "Issue: " . $_POST['issue']
. "\n" . "How did the issue happen?: " . $_POST['how']
. "\n" . "When did the issue occur?: " . $_POST['when']
. "\n" . "Have you done anything to try correcting the issue?: " . $_POST['customerTry'];

$to = 'murtorius@gmail.com';
$from = $_POST['email'];
$from_name = $_POST['fullName'];

//attachment files path array
$files = $_FILES['userfile'];
$subject = 'Customer Contact From Service Form';

if (array_key_exists('userfile', $_FILES)) {
    // First handle the upload
    // Don't trust provided filename - same goes for MIME types
    // See http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php#114004 for more thorough upload validation
    $uploadfile = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), sha1($_FILES['userfile']['name']));
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) {
        // Upload handled successfully
        // Now create a message
        // This should be somewhere in your include_path
        require 'php-mailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';
        $mail = new PHPMailer;
        $mail->setFrom($from, $from_name);
        $mail->addAddress($to, 'TEST');
        $mail->Subject = $subject;
        $mail->msgHTML($message);
        // Attach the uploaded file
        $mail->addAttachment($uploadfile, 'Photos');
        if (!$mail->send()) {
            $msg .= "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
        } else {
            $msg .= "Message sent!";
        }
    } else {
        $msg .= 'Failed to move file to ' . $uploadfile;
    }
}
```

I changed the input file field name to 'userfile[]', but I get this:

```
Warning: sha1() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in /home/zucora/service.zucora.com/processContact.php on line 35

Warning: move_uploaded_file() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in /home/zucora/service.zucora.com/processContact.php on line 36
```

If I change the name to 'userfile' (without []) I get a blank screen and no email.

Comment: Don't build your own mime emails. Use phpmailer or swiftmailer. All of that mime fiddling code will be reduced to a SINGLE `->addAttachment(...)`-type call.  And if `mail()` returns `true`, it's not a PHP problem. PHP did its equivalent of walking your envelope down to the street corner and dropped it into the mailbox. If the letter gets lost after that, it's not PHP's problem - it's the postal service's. Go look at your mail server logs.

Comment: No one has an answer?

Comment: `var_dump($_FILES)`, and hopefully something will become a bit more clear...